# Postgres- Script to create a script to create existing indexes on given tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with a lot of tables in it. Some of them have names which start with "mytable_". Those tables have some indexes. Now I need to move those indexes also to different server which has similar tables.

I would like to have a script which will create all those indexes that are in given tables on my local server.

Also I would like to make it this way that if this index is already created it will not crash.

How can it be done in Postgres (pg admin)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `pg_get_indexdef()` to extra all the index definitions:

```
select replace(pg_get_indexdef(format('%I.%I', schemaname, indexname)::regclass), ' INDEX ', ' INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ')||';' as ddl
from pg_indexes
where schemaname = 'public'
  and tablename like 'mytable\_%';
```

The `replace` is used to "inject" the `IF NOT EXISTS` so that the statement won't fail if such an index is already present in the target database.

Just spool the result of that query to a file.